# jquery: 2 lists one of which is sortable, second is connected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have 2 lists:

```
<ul id="sortable">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="connected">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

First list (id="sortable") is sortable and items can be checked. When item is checked it is appear into the second list (connected). When nothing is checked then second list is empty.

Items into the second list must appear in the same sequence as in the sortable list. I can use jquery functions like

```
.insertBefore() or .insertAfter()
```

but I don't know after or before which item insert new item. How to find out that?

Comment: I am still wondering how to you check an LI element. Can you share you r complete code or more preferably, set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: I haven't yet complete code. Item can be checked by clicking on checkbox or just by clicking on itself and background will be changed e.g.

Comment: I can tell you the logic but I am not sure of it till I see the complete code

Comment: @Mandeep Jain, I appreciate your help. You can tell me only logic/algorithm step by step and I will write complete code by myself. My own solution (logic/algorithm, haven't written yet) includes not only js but php and mysql. I want to compare different solutions and choose the best one.

Comment: ok. while checking, find the item checked above the currently checked item and search it in the second list and insertAfter it.

Comment: I have forgotten about .prev() and .next() functions which will help me to find the item checked above the currently checked item. Previous your comment this is "+1" but I can not find out how to up your that advice which should be obvious for me.

Comment: I m sorry I didnt get you. you can make use of the prevAll() jquery funtion. You can do something like $("CurrentlyCheckedBox").prevAll().find(".checkbox-class:checked:last") to find the last selected checkox. I am not sure of whether it will work properly